# Accessibility - Screen reader not reading tabs count

Tags: bootstrap-4, accessibility, uiaccessibility, nvda

I'm trying to make the bootstrap tab accessible - the screen reader should read tabs as http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tabpanel2.shtml (tab 1 of 1/ tab 1 of 2) but the bootstrap tabs always reads as tab 1 of 1 for all the tab items. If I give the role="tab" to the `li` items, it reads as 1 of 5/ 2 of 5 etc. but it does not read the expanded and collapsed state correctly. If I give role="tab" to anchor items, expanded & collapsed state is read correctly in screen reader bu the tab count is read wrongly as 1 of 1 always. Any ideas/ insights would be really helpful.

Find my markup below:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill nav-tabs-horizontal slider tab-bar" id="secondary-tab" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link active" id="summary-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#summary-details" role="tab"  aria-controls="summary-details">Summary</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" id="coverage-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#coverage" role="tab" aria-controls="coverage">Details</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" id="payment-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#payment" onclick="getPaymentHistory()" role="tab" aria-controls="payment">Transactions</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" id="loans-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#loanstab" role="tab" aria-controls="loanstab">Loan</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" id="correspondence-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#correspondence" role="tab" aria-controls="correspondence" >Statements</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the parent `role="presentation"`. I think the `a role="tab"`, should be a direct child of `role="tablist"`...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill nav-tabs-horizontal slider tab-bar" id="secondary-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-link nav-item active" id="summary-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#summary-details" role="tab" aria-controls="summary-details">Summary</a>
        <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="coverage-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#coverage" role="tab" aria-controls="coverage">Details</a>
        <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="payment-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#payment" onclick="getPaymentHistory()" role="tab" aria-controls="payment">Transactions</a>
        <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="loans-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#loanstab" role="tab" aria-controls="loanstab">Loan</a>
        <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="correspondence-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#correspondence" role="tab" aria-controls="correspondence" >Statements</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get screen reader to announce " Summary tab 1 of 5" by adding "aria-label" in the li's. Per your code, it can be:
    `var $tabList=$("li[role='presentation']"),
    len= $tabList.length, count=0;
    $tabList.each(function(){
        count++;
        var $linkName=$(this).find("a").text();
        $(this).attr("aria-label",$linkName+" tab"+count+" of"+len);
    });`

...